# AttributeError: module in Django, Python

Tags: python, django, attributeerror

Getting the following error

```
File "C:\Users\abc\Projects\ecom\src\ecom\urls.py", line 33, in <module>
path('products/', views.ProductListView.as_view()),
AttributeError: module 'ecom.views' has no attribute 'ProductListView'
```

ecom/src/ecom/url.py

```
from products.views import ProductListView, product_list_view

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
path('', views.home_page),
path('login/', views.login_page),
path('register/', views.register_page), 
path('products/', views.ProductListView.as_view()),
path('products-fbv/', views.product_list_view),
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

ecom/src/products/views.py

```
from django.views.generic import ListView
from django.shortcuts import render


from .models import Product


class ProductListView(ListView):
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    template_name="products/list.html"



def product_list_view(request):
    queryset=Product.objects.all()
    context={
    'qs':queryset
    }
    return render(request,"products/list.html", context)
```

Tried changing urlpatterns and products nothing worked.

Comment: Then the module is `product.views`, not `ecom.views`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you specify that the `views.py` file is `ecom/src/products/views.py`. So that means that the module is `products.views`. You actually already import that. But in your `urls.py`, you write `views.ProductListView`, whereas that `views` module is actually the one of `ecom`. You thus should not reference it through `views.ProductListView`, but for example import it like you did, and then reference it directly.

If you thus want to reference this view, you can use:

```
from products.views import ProductListView, product_list_view

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home_page),
    path('login/', views.login_page),
    path('register/', views.register_page), 
    path('products/', ProductListView.as_view()),
    path('products-fbv/', product_list_view),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```